# Prove $f$ is bounded (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Could someone please help me prove the following and tell me their thought process as well if possible?

Let $f$ be a continuous *real-valued* function on the closed, bounded subset $S$ of the complex plane. Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to show that $f$ is bounded.

The hint given was: "If this is not the case then there exists a sequence of points $z_n \in S$ such that $f(z_n)>n$.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: A closed bounded subset of ${\Bbb C}$ is compact. Every sequence has a convergent subsequence. (IMO: It's not really complex analysis)

Comment: That should be $|f(z_n)| > n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is not bounded. Then let $z_n$ be the sequence from the hint.
As noted by H. H. Rugh we have a convergent subsequence $z_{n_k} \to \tilde z \in S$. Now continuity gives us that $f(z_{n_k}) \to f(\tilde z)< N \in \mathbb N$. Then for sufficiently large $K\in \mathbb N$ we have that $f(z_{n_k})< N+1$, for all $k \geq K$. But this contradicts the hint. Thus our assumption is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin for your help! Just one thing, how does $f(z_{n_k})<N+1$ contradict $f(z_n)>n$?

Comment: Because N is a fixed value so some $n_k >N+1$.